# QT_INTERFACES and signal definitions

Tags: c++, qt, interface, signals

How to define signals in interfaces?

```
class ISomeInterface
{
    signals:
        virtual void added(const QString& id) = 0;
        virtual void removed(const QString& id) = 0;

    // bla, other methods
}
```

Afaik, signals should not virtual but if I want to define that a signal needs to be implemented in classes implementing the interface => how to do this? Or do you simply make them non-abstract... but interfaces have no Q_OBJECT declaration here! Is the correct code generated in this cases? On top... you'll need a bad (f*****g) cast to QObject if you want to connect to the signals.

```
class ISomeInterface
{
    signals:
        void added(const QString& id);
        void removed(const QString& id);

    // bla, other methods
}
```

Or do you try to implement it that way?

```
class ISomeInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    signals:
        void added(const QString& id);
        void removed(const QString& id);

    // bla, other methods
}

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(ISomeInterface, "ISomeInterface")
```

.. but this way I can inherit from only one interface (QObject does not support multiple inheritance).

**Conclusion: As suggested, I would go with the first one.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Define signals as virtual abstract protected methods. (Instead of protected you may use signal: keyword).
2. Final object must interhit your interface and QObject
3. Cast pointer to interface to QObject * with dynamic_cast
4. Connect pointer to necessary slots

You may check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943496/declare-abstract-signal-in-interface-class/17943699#17943699) for some solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Qt does not handle multiple inheritance from QObject (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131357/multiple-inheritance-with-qobject-base)), so you can't derive all your interfaces from it (otherwise you won't be able to derive from multiple interfaces). So instead you might have something like `IQObject` interface with

```
virtual QObject* qObject() = 0
```

method, so you don't need to cast them to QObject all the time.

As for providing interface for signals - no such thing. What you can do is make them virtual abstract, that'll work if you really need to enforce this compile-time check (because `signals:` is just an alias for `protected:`). If you don't, just check the return value from the `connect()` method.

Comment: The `qObject` method is guaranteed to outperform `dynamic_cast<QObject*>(pInterface)` and thus is a good idea. There are no guarantees about `dynamic_cast`'s complexity, while `qObject` has a constant cost. The implementation `QObject * MyClass::qObject() { return this; }` amounts to simple pointer arithmetic.