# Signal/Slot base-Class Multi inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots

in my Qt multithread programm I want to implement a QObject-based baseclass, so that every class derived from it cann use its signals and slots (for example to throw an error).

I implemented `MyQObject : public QObject{...}`. But for classes that derive from QWidget I cannot multi inher from QWidget and MyQObject.

I can solve the problem by calling the slot directly by QMetaObject::invokeMethod(...), but i am interested if there would be another way to solve this problem.

Comment: `QWidget` already derives from `QObject`. You don't need to inherit `QObject` again. In other words, you can use signals/slots in your `QWidget` sub classes.

Comment: That is the problem. I want to add my own signals in a "global" base-class.

Comment: What are the use-cases of such global signals or slots ? Maybe you could change the design and not use signal/slots for what you want to achieve ? Like having a composition instead of inheritance and directly call what your need on the `MyQObjectAsComposition`.

Comment: This would be a solid solution in my case. I guess i will think about this. But this question is more general. Someone may need a Signal-Base-Class/Interface.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131357/multiple-inheritance-with-qobject-base?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance with QObject can be done following these rules:

1. Only one of the parents class can be a QObject/QWidget
2. The QObject parent have to be the first parent in the initialization.

There's a trick that allows you to declare a signal like function in a non-qobject interface and then declaring it inheriting that interface using composition. Take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943496/declare-abstract-signal-in-interface-class), it may be useful.